# How to remove custom WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove all unnecessary tabs from the WooCommerce product page in the backend. I've already found an article (
[How to remove woocommerce tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811930/how-to-remove-woocommerce-tab)), which describes, how to remove the description, review or additional information tab in the backend. (e.g. `unset( $tabs['reviews'] );`).

[image]

The last two tabs are from the WooCommerce Subscription plugin and our CRM. If I use `var_dump($tabs)`, the two tabs aren't shown in the array and can't be removed the same way. How can I find the name of the tabs and how can I remove them?

Comment: deactivate WooCommerce Subscription plugin and check

Comment: I am guessing the WC Subscription plugin and/or your CRM plugin utilizes the `woocommerce_product_tabs` filter with higher priority (it us executed later) than your filter callback - therefore at the time of your callback being executed, those custom tabs are not set yet. Try calling that filter with a higher priority (e.g. 9999).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the wrong code and article for your need.

`woocommerce_product_tabs` filter hook is for frontend single product page tabs not for backend.

for the background product data tabs, you need to use [woocommerce_product_data_tabs](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_product_data_tabs) filter hook.